# Do you use the original (German) apple keyboard/keyboard layout when programming on mac?

Tags: macos

I'm a programmer, working with different languages/Formats (Java, Python, XML, HTML, Objective-C etc.). From time to I've to work on a Mac and I'm not very comfortable with the German keyboard layout for programming.

Is there somebody with the same problem and, if so, how did you solve it?

Comment: why is the german keyboard so different? (I have no knowledge of a mackeyboard)

Comment: All brackets signs have bad key combinations. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311244/keyboard-layout-for-international-programmers

Comment: For different reasons some characters often used in programming like [] are on their 'usual' places but not printed on the keys (design reason?) or they are only reachable via strange key combinations (\ = ALT+SHIFT+7). Pic (xl!) http://tim.feddern.org/Verkauf/Tastatur,%20Maus,%20DVI/Tastatur_1.jpg

Comment: Good heavens, that's not a nice keyboard layout for programmers is it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently did an internship in England and used this opportunity to switch to the English keyboard layout. The switch was nearly completely straightforward and I can heartily recommend it, especially since you can still type the German umlauts very well on the English keyboard layout (Alt+u, then a/o/u types the corresponding umlaut; Alt+s types “ß”).

The keys used for programming are much easier reachable, especially “`[]`” and “`{}`” (which are both on “`ü`” and “`+`”). Also, “`/`” and “`\`” better placed. The only think I absolutely **hate** is the placement of the “`+`” key because it requires the shift key!

Comment: I think VB.NET is an international-keyboard friendly language: no ";", few curly and angle brackets. ;-)

Comment: Started yesterday to work with an English layout and it's great (although I've still the german keyboard). To reach the umlauts via ALT+... is (on a win-PC) not out of the box, but I'll fix that one too with microsofts layout editor .

Comment: @KonradRudolph Do you mean the UK English keyboard? I cannot reproduce ALT+U plus a/o/u as you described. Is it only valid for macOS? However, for the US keyboard it works as described in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1142924/umlaut-%C3%A4-%C3%B6-%C3%BC-on-english-us-layout/1142932#1142932) post.

Comment: @Patrick The question was about programming on macOS. So yes, this is on macOS (the “Alt” key has since been renamed to “Option” on the keyboard).

Comment: You could use the + on your num keypad!

Comment: @Legolas I never use keyboards with numpad. Not that it matters, I haven’t thought about this in over ten years. It isn’t an issue for me any more.

Answer (score 146):

**[EurKEY](https://eurkey.steffen.bruentjen.eu)** has all the advantages of the US standard layout (which is perfect for programming) combined with an easy way to access most western-european characters. For instance, you get a german ö with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, or an ß with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>.

It is available for Linux, Mac and Windows and it's free. Newer Linux distributions have it already included (xkeyboard-config 2.12).

[image: EurKEY layout]

Please note that I am the author of EurKEY.

Comment: Shouldn't you disclose your affiliation with your proposed solution?

Comment: @BenjaminW. For what reason? I'm running this open source project altruistically at my own cost having no ads. I believe this answer (a layout for programmers that can be used on mac and other systems.) provides a good solution to the question.

Comment: Because of [this policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) and its discussion in [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361284/3266847), I'd say.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Does this suffice?

Comment: Sure! Not trying to be an ass here, I think it's awesome that people like you create stuff and open source it.

Comment: I like it. Would be great if MS and Linux could add this as a default to choose from. Also that the EU could adopt this as a standard and you could also purchase the Layaut as hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Related sad story: I am often unhappy about the keyboard layout (especially the placement on CapsLock, Ctrl, Apple key, which is different on Mac and Dell, and I have to use both), but I found that I absolutely cannot handle a (software) keyboard layout that does not correspond to what is printed on the actual hardware keycaps.

I think I could deal with a keyboard without any keycaps at all, but once they do not say what they do, I get very conscious about my typing and mess up completely.

So short of using an actual programmer-friendly USB keyboard I am trapped with what the OS/hardware vendor thinks is good for me.

**Update:** The guy sitting at the desk in front of me has covered his keyboard with the star-spangled banner is typing *through* that...

Comment: Absolutely same with me. I'm not able to handle keyboards where the keys don't do what's printed on. I think, I buy me an English keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a blank keyboard from http://www.daskeyboard.com

I've been eyeing it up for awhile now.

Comment: I actually wanted to buy this one yesterday, but it costs 99 Euros!